# find with size option does not report correctly on busybox

Tags: android, performance, shell, find, busybox

Below  `find` doesnt quite respect the `-size` parameter . I have to use `pipes` to get the job done. I read a snippet somewhere  that size relates to `datablocks` and there's rounding taking place but this is far from sensible for `size`....what  you see below 
My question is  specific - is this a  skinned `find` version for android aka use anor there's something I am missing while running it .

```
find  /data/s*2/data -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d  -size -10k |  sort
```

o/p

```
/data/sdext2/data/us.zoom.videomeetings
/data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre
```

actual size

```
/#du -hs /data/sdext2/data/us.zoom.videomeetings
16K /data/sdext2/data/us.zoom.videomeetings
/#du -hs /data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre
2.2M    /data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre
/#
```

I can get this done using `du` and `pipe` to `-exec` but this Q is about a solution using a single pass as would be if offered by `find`

.

**Update** : from comment " *please add output of busybox stat of each file to your question* " 
 here goes...

```
    /#busybox  stat /data/sdext2/data/us.zoom.videomeetings
  File: /data/sdext2/data/us.zoom.videomeetings
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: b342h/45890d    Inode: 189044      Links: 4
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (10325/ u0_a325)   Gid: (10325/ u0_a325)
Access: 2021-08-31 13:09:17.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2021-08-31 20:59:13.974177753 +0530
Change: 2021-08-31 20:59:13.974177753 +0530
/#busybox  stat /data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre                                                                                        
  File: /data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: b342h/45890d    Inode: 155677      Links: 13
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (10341/ u0_a341)   Gid: (10341/ u0_a341)
Access: 2021-08-16 14:58:55.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2021-08-31 14:13:51.225999993 +0530
Change: 2021-08-31 17:34:57.068960585 +0530
/#
```

Comment: please add output of `busybox stat` of each file to your question

Comment: did that && posted  o/p in Q

Comment: ok thx. Any way we can `hs` of  dir  with size filter ( My OS's `du` doesnt like the `threshold` op ) - `Single pass ( aka. pipleless  )`. We can do this`piped`, I know

Answer (score 1):

`find` is behaving correctly.

You are trying to check `-size` of `-type d`.

Directories are just files that contain information about other files. [1]

When you run `du -hs /data/sdext2/data/xeus.timbre`, it  computes the total size used by all the referenced files and sub-directories (and recursively the files and sub-directories referenced by those sub-directories), not the size used by `xeus.timbre` itself (which your `stat` shows is 4096 bytes).

---

[1] From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem):

> Unix directories do not contain files. Instead, they contain the names of files paired with references to so-called inodes, which in turn contain both the file and its metadata (owner, permissions, time of last access, etc., but no name). Multiple names in the file system may refer to the same file, a feature termed a hard link.

Comment: ok thx. Any way we can hs of dir with size filter ( My OS's du doesnt like the threshold op ) - Single pass ( aka. pipleless  ). We can do thispiped, I know